# Python send_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, telegram, telegram-bot

I am writing a parser bot that checks a site for a domain name through the whois service. In the terminal the parsing goes fine and the information is displayed, but when need to send this text in the chat, an error is generated (send_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text')

**this is just a link check:**

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['getpng'])
def get_screenshot(message):
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['getpng'])
    def get_screenshot(message):
    uid = message.chat.id
    url = ""
    try:
        url = message.text.split(' ')[1]
    except IndexError:
        bot.send_message(uid, 'You have not entered URL!')
        return
    if not validators.url(url):
        bot.send_message(uid, 'URL is invalid!')
    else:

**this is the problematic part of the code:**

        browser = webdriver.Chrome()
        browser.get('https://www.nic.ru/whois/')
        input1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rc-web-client"]/div/div/div[1]/main/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/input')
        input1.send_keys(url)
        time.sleep(2)
        button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rc-web-client"]/div/div/div[1]/main/div[1]/div[1]/div/button/span[1]')
        button.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        infa = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rc-web-client"]/div/div/div[1]/main/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[2]/a[1]')
        infa1 = infa.text
        #print(infa1)
        bot.send_message(infa1)
```

I get that error when I run the code.
why is the text in the infa1 not visible? how can i solve this?

UPD:

```
Возникло исключение: TypeError       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: get_screenshot)
send_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'
  File "C:\Users\Petyal\Desktop\something.py", line 41, in get_screenshot (Current frame)
    bot.send_message(infa1)
  File "C:\Users\Petyal\Desktop\something.py", line 56, in <module>
    bot.infinity_polling()
```

Comment: whats the func signature of send_message?

Comment: You'll help us by including the entire stack backtrace.

Comment: do you mean send all code?

Comment: You should edit into your question the _full_ error message with the stack trace, which includes the line of code where the error happened, and the function calls that led to that point. Also show the definition of `send_message()`.

Comment: @balmy i edited

Comment: Don't use pictures of text or links to code - edit __the text__ into your question. You only need provide the definition line of bot.send_message() showing its parameters.

Comment: I don't fully understand what exactly you want to see. sorry...

Comment: Don't put pictures of text in your question, put the text itself, by copy/paste. And for the definition of send_message(), paste the complete text of the `def send_message(...):` line into your question, not a link. Image hosting sites can disappear or remove unused links, and code repositories can change or be deleted, so relying on links to these could leave your question useless. Plus I for one don't like clicking random off-site links.

Comment: I hope I understood correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you missed the chat_id parameter in the send_message function

Try adding a parameter:

```
bot.send_message(chat_id, text)
```